# Write the same values that contained in 2 linked list into another linked list

Tags: c++

I want to write function that creates new singly linked list and write into it the same values that contained in two another singly linked lists. And I wrote  down solution with nested 'for' loop and I cannot understand why it doesn't work.

```
struct list {
    int data;
    list *next;
};

// Adding
list* add(list* l, int x)
{
    if (l == NULL)
    {
        l = new list;
        l->data = x;
        l->next = NULL;

        return l;
    }

    list* temp = l;
    while (temp->next != NULL)
    {
        temp = temp->next;
    }

    list* p = new list;
    p->data = x;
    p->next = NULL;

    temp->next = p;

    return l;
}
// That function generates SegFault 11
list* foo(list* l1, list* l2) {
    list* new_list;

    for (list* temp1 = l1 ; temp1 != NULL; temp1 = temp1->next) {
        for (list* temp2 = l2; temp2 != NULL; temp2 = temp2->next) {
            if (temp1->data == temp2->data) {
                new_list = add(new_list, temp1->data);
            }
        }
    }

    return new_list;
}

// show() code

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    list* l;

    l = add(l, 13);
    l = add(l, 34);
    l = add(l, 13);
    l = add(l, 7);
    l = add(l, 90);

    show(l);
    cout << endl;

    list* l2;
    l2 = add(l2, 13);
    l2 = add(l2, 61);
    l2 = add(l2, 48);
    l2 = add(l2, 7);
    l2 = add(l2, 90);
    cout << endl;

    show(l2);
    cout <<  endl;

    list* l3 = foo(l, l2); // 13 7 90
    show(l3);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected '13 7 90'. But received Segmentation Fault. Why?
I editted code with add() function

Comment: Well, that seems a good point to learn how to debug your programs stepping through line by line and inspecting the state of the variables, and if they're changing as you intended with your code.

Comment: @Dmitriy Usually a more interesting question sounds like "And I wrote down solution with nested 'for' loop and I cannot understand why it works!":)

Comment: where is the code for `add`?

Comment: @Dmitriy What will be the result list for two lists like { 1, 1 } and  { 1 }?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

list* l = NULL; //  Just initialize it to NULL in main.

list* l2 = NULL; // Just initialize it to NULL in main.

/* Now your code will work fine.*/

Comment: This is a code-only answer. For this to become a good answer you need to explain why.

Comment: When we create a pointer variable in c++ without initialising it then it points to some garbage value.

Answer (score 1):

You must initialize all your pointer values (list* : l, l2, new_list, next) to something. In C++ (11 and newer) you initialize them to nullptr, in older C++ and C you initialize them to NULL. If you don't do that, they have a random value and your code is reading to and writing from the memory that it does not own.

NOTE: I'm assuming that add() will allocate a new list sturcture when you pass it a null-pointer.

Comment: `Add` has been added and surprise, surprise, you're right! Have an upvote.